# Python: Inject attribute into object created by C library

Tags: python, lxml, code-injection, setattr

I'm trying to inject an attribute into `lxml.etree._Element`, but as that module is completely implemented in C, `setattr` fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
    setattr(node.getroottree().getroot(), "attributeName", value)
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'attributeName'
```

The use case: I have a function that extracts text from a XML file by XPath and replaces `$(ENV)`-like matches by the corresponding value. Therefore I don't want to have to pass the variables dictionary (e.g. `{"ENV" : "replacement"}` to that function each time. Instead it would be easier to just have an attribute at a fixed place (XML root in my code). I could do a dumb workaround but injecting a Python attribute would be the best way. I cannot use a global variable because each XML file can have different variable values.

So, any way to inject something into C-based classes/objects?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You generally can't, as instances of C-defined types typically don't have per-instance `__dict__` entries to hold arbitrary attributes.

A workaround for cases when a subclass or wrapper class won't work is to create a helper dictionary at the module level that maps the object you have to additional information. If the object you have isn't hashable, you can use `id(obj)` instead.

So, for example, you could store a dictionary associated with the id of each root object:

```
# Module level, setting up the data store
from collections import defaultdict
extra_info = defaultdict(dict) # Creates empty dicts for unknown keys

# Saving the info
root = node.getroottree().getroot()
extra_info[id(root)]["ENV"] = "replacement"

# Retrieving it later
root = node.getroottree().getroot()
info = extra_info[id(root)]
```

Comment: Well, wrapping the class won't work because then `node.getroottree().getroot()` will still point to the non-wrapped object. I only have the `node` available to my function ;) At the moment, I have the workaround `node.getroottree().docinfo.URL = repr(variablesDict)` (because I don't need the XML URL and that is one of few attributes that are writable), and then using `eval` to create the dictionary again.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. Your workaround would work as well, but I think I'll keep mine as it will destroy the variables together with the XML document.

Comment: Yeah, you would need to use a `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary` to manage the lifecycle if you wanted the extra info to go away at the same time as the original object.